# Java: Accessing Windows files from Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, windows, permissions, centos

I've got a Java program that saves a new PDF file to a shared network location.

On Windows, it works fine, using backslashes

```
serverDirName=\\\\10.20.1.1\\c$\\input
```

To try skip all the complexity of permissions, I've set the sharing on that folder in Windows to Read/Write for "Everyone".

I'd like to try run the program from a linux server.
Straight off the bat, I get:

```
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\10.20.1.1\e$\input/8106070121089/Doctor-Diagnosis-201003291.pdf (No such file or directory)
```

So I tried switching to:

```
serverDirName=//10.20.1.1/e$/input
```

and got:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Directory '/10.20.1.1/e$/input/8103205007085' could not be created
```

I presume there's some basic network requirements that I'm lacking, in order to communicate with a Windows machine, but any idea what that is?

(OS is Centos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access windows directory you should mount windows shared directory to your linux server.

See https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares

After this you'll be able to use this windows directory as a local linux directory.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I figured the answer was Samba, but kind of needed confirmation.  Will try it out quick and report back

Answer (score 0):

Check with **java.io.File.separator** for **backlash** according to OS.